# WooCommerce update Order modified date

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce, orders

i want update order modified date using below code but it's not working (it's set current now date time).

Code:

```
$order = wc_get_order( 5029 );
$now = new DateTime();
$now->modify('-4 day');
$order->set_date_modified($now->getTimestamp());
$order->save();
```

woocommerce 7.9.0

Comment: "Not working" as in doesn't update at all, or updates with a wrong time (like exactly that of when you are executing this code, perhaps)?

Comment: @CBroe it's set current now date

Comment: Setting it to the current time is likely part of what happens when the `save` method is called. You'd have to go and look into what's happening in there in more detail then, I suppose. But _why_ are you trying to do this in the first place? This rather sounds like you are trying to "abuse" this field for some additional purpose, that it wasn't meant for in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can't alter the modified date when using `save()` method as this method overwrite itself the modified date, with the real "current" modified date.

So It requires a direct SQL query on the database related tables `wp_posts`, `wp_wc_orders` to alter the modified date.

Comment: i test that, it print correct date (-4 day from now) but when get get_date_modified again (without update) it's return now date time. It seemed after update by my code (your code) it's set now date time for order modified date automatically

Comment: I have found out why it doesn't work. I have updated my answer.